# Woocommerce how to chang the cart class from plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am writing a `plugin` to let customer add some photos to the cart (and therefore to the order).

If I add protected `$pictures = array()` parameters to the cart class, it works and I have it in the "meta" database. With `getter` and `setter` it should do the job.

I know that it's not good practice to change a class in the core of woocommerce.

**Question:**

How can I change the class from my plugin? Because if I override the class (i.e: cart2) it won't work as all the parents declaration of the rest of the core pages won't be affected.

Thanks for your help.
Best,
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Ok instead changing a core class I found that woocommerce is using filters. So my solution below :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filterYoushoesCart', 10, 4 );
function filterYoushoesCart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ){
    $cart_item_data['photos'] = array();

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: in the function.php of my plugin